# Problem with generic class and class Type

Tags: java, class, generics, arraylist, arguments

I have created a (generic) class Store, which I use to get 3 stores(smithy, jeweler and bookstore). The store is basically just an ArrayList, which holds different objects, that can be bought in each store. Now I want to limit the smithy to only hold weapons, the jeweler to only hold rings, etc.

I tried realizing that like this:

```
    Store<Weapon> smithy = new Store<>();
    Store<Ring> jeweler = new Store<>();
    Store<Scroll> bookstore = new Store<>();
```

However do I get an error later on in the code, because the method only accepts the type`(Object, Store<Object>)` and not `(Object,Store<Weapon>)`. But the Weapon class is a subclass of my Object class, so I don't understand why this is a problem.

My Store class:

```
public class Store <T extends Object>{
/...
}
```

My Object Class:

```
public class Object {

    //Konstruktor
    public Object() {
    
    }
}
```

My Weapon class :

```
public class Weapon extends Object  {
    //Konstruktor
    public Weapon () {
        super();
    };
```

The piece of code I get the problem in:

```
this.myPlayer.buy(this.smithy.getItemAt(itemNr), this.smithy);
```

The buy method:

```
public void buy(Object obj, Store<Object> store){
//...}
```

the error:

```
the method buy(Object,Store<Object>) in the type Player is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Store<Weapon>)
```

Since I have three different stores with each their own kind of Objects(Weapon, Ring, Scroll) I cannot just change the buy method to `(Object, Store<Weapon>)`. And writing three methods for each store seems a bit much to me.

I appreciate your helping.

Comment: `Object` is `java.lang.Object`.  You can't use this name, pick another.

Comment: Don't use `Object` as name. generics are invariant; `Apple` is not a valid thing when you need a `Fruit` (whereas 'plain java' is covariant, and Apples and Pears CAN be used when you need a Fruit). Opt into covariance: `public void buy(Item item, Store<? extends Item> store) {}` is all you need.